# Problems with Post-Build Event in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I am running into an issue with my Post Build Event in VS 2010, I am recieving the following errors on my projects, but I don't know what ths means and I cannot seem to even edit the original Post-build Event. Let me know what my options are? thanks in advance.

```
Error   1   The command "copy "C:\Users\Paul.Rykiel\Desktop\Sitecore Notes\YAFIntegrationSource\YAFIntegrationSource\YetAnotherForum.NET\Bin\YAF.Classes.Utils.*" "d:\projects\Sitecore\yaf2\Sitecore\www\bin\"" exited with code 1.    YAF.Classes.Utils
Error   2   The command "copy "C:\Users\Paul.Rykiel\Desktop\Sitecore Notes\YAFIntegrationSource\YAFIntegrationSource\YetAnotherForum.NET\Bin\YAF.Classes.UI.*" "d:\projects\Sitecore\yaf2\Sitecore\www\bin\"" exited with code 1.   YAF.Classes.UI
Error   3   The command "copy "C:\Users\Paul.Rykiel\Desktop\Sitecore Notes\YAFIntegrationSource\YAFIntegrationSource\YetAnotherForum.NET\Bin\YAF.Classes.Base.*" "d:\projects\Sitecore\yaf2\Sitecore\www\bin\"" exited with code 1. YAF.Classes.Base
Error   4   The command "copy "C:\Users\Paul.Rykiel\Desktop\Sitecore Notes\YAFIntegrationSource\YAFIntegrationSource\YetAnotherForum.NET\Bin\YAF.Classes.Config.*" "d:\projects\Sitecore\yaf2\Sitecore\www\bin\"" exited with code 1.   YAF.Classes.Config
```

Comment: Does the target folder exist?  Do you have rights to copy files there?  Try running the command at a command prompt.

Comment: yes, the folders exist, i changed the folders from d: to c: ... as the "d" drive is my DVD drive. but for some reason when I edited the Post Build Event and saved it, ran my build... it still points to d. thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:
 1. Remove the post-build event

1. Fix the commands defined in the post-build event
2. Fix the underlying problem that's preventing the commands from working
3. Ignore the failures?

It's not clear *why* you can't edit the post-build event.  You can't find where in the UI to edit it?  These are unfortunately different depending on the type of project you're working on.  I think we'll need more information (like what you've tried) in order to provide more help.

Comment: I did try to edit the POST BUILD EVENT by going into Tools >> Properties >> build events, I took the option to "Edit Post build" and I replaced everything... saved it, and my changes did not seem to take. I want to copy to a folder on the "c" drive not "d" drive. My D drive is DVD. thank you for trying to help, i so appreciate your time.

Comment: everyone thank you for your responses. this problem is no longer an issue, what I was missing, was that post-build is per project, not isolated to one solution ... so I had to go into each soluation to change my post-build. Thanks for all of your help!